# Счётчик вызовов рекурсивной функции

Tags: delphi, рекурсия

Каким образом **внутри** рекурсивной функции определить, что она вызвана первый раз?
Т.е. если я хочу что-то сделать перед её вызовом, приходится везде в коде писать:

```
// Пердварительные действия
// Вызов функции
```

Хотелось бы чтобы "Пердварительные действия" выполнялись автоматически при вызове функции и не приходилось постоянно о них не забывать и засорять код. Можно конечно сделать другую функцию, которая выполнит данные действия и вызовет функцию, но может есть красивое решение? Возможно создать счётчик вызовов и при =0 выполнять инициализацию?

Comment: Как параметр функции передавайте ещё `bool` флаг `first` и проверяйте его. При запуске метода передавайте `true`, а дальше уже `false`.

Comment: @Suvitruf, Всё гениальное просто) Спасибо! Я его default true сделал, а внутри уже с false вызываю, минимум исправлений в коде. 
А всё-таки счётчик организовать возможно?

Comment: Ну сделайте не `bool`, а `int`. Передавайте при старте 0, проверяйте на 0. Внутри при вызове наращивайте на 1.

Comment: @Suvitruf: Почему бы не как ответ?

Comment: В случаях, когда ничто не помогает, "последний довод" - объявить счётчик как глобальную переменную

Answer (score 4):

Сделайте так:

```
function CallMyRecursion(Param: TMyParam): TMyResult
begin
// предварительные действия
Result := MyRecursion(Param);
end;
```

А в коде вместо:

```
// Предварительные действия
MyResult := MyRecursion(Param); // Вызов функции
```

Пишите:

```
MyResult := CallMyRecursion(Param);
```

Comment: Это я в самом начале написал) "Можно конечно сделать другую функцию, которая выполнит данные действия и вызовет функцию"
Помнится как-то делался счётчик вызывов через типизированную константу... был там какой-то трик

Comment: @Isaev, Вам дело говорят. Понятно что delphi это не C++, и никто не требует огромного быстродействия от этого языка. Но зачем же мнимой красотой кода и другими излишествами убивать производительность на корню. Этот вариант не вносит дополнительный оверхед. Вариант же с проверкой - на каждой итерации отрабатывает и жжет драгоценное процессорное время, хотя алгоритмически известно что условие сработает только  в первый раз.

Comment: @sba, всё верно, правильный ответ был в первом же комментарии, я просто уже ради интереса пытался вспомнить старый трюк. Не зря же вопрос был о счётчике вызовов. Вспомнил наконец)

Answer (score 1):

> Помнится как-то делался счётчик вызывов через типизированную константу...

Вы имеете в виду:

```
type
  TRunCounter = (rcFirst, rcSecond);
...
function CallMyRecursion(..., ACounter: TRunCounter = rcFirst): ...
begin
    if (ACounter = rcFirst) then
    begin
       // предварительные действия
    end;

    Result := CallMyRecursion(..., rcSecond);
end;

//Вызов
SomeValue := CallMyRecursion(...);
```

Все таки вариант с boolean больше подходит, не нужно плодить лишних типов.

```
function CallMyRecursion(..., IsFirstRun: boolean = true): ...
begin
    if (IsFirstRun) then
    begin
       // предварительные действия
    end;

    Result := CallMyRecursion(..., false);
end;

//Вызов
SomeValue := CallMyRecursion(...);
```

**Upd1**: 
При использовании типизованных констант в качестве инициализируемых переменных в области видимости метода в Delphi наблюдается недокументированный побочный эффект - данные, записанные в локальные типизованные константы, сохраняются между вызовами подпрограмм.

Также директива компиляции {$J+}

По умолчанию директива компиляции установлена в {$J-}, при этом типизированные константы нельзя изменять при выполнении программы; Константа в таком случае выступает в роли  константы, а не переменной и только для чтения. Тем не менее если установить директиву компилятора {$J+}, типизированным константам можно присвоить значение; они ведут себя как инициализированные переменные. [источник](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Writeable_typed_constants_(Delphi))

В таком случае можно написать следующее:

```
{$J+}
function CallMyRecursion() : string;
сonst
  IsFirstRun : Boolean = True;
begin
  if IsFirstRun then
  begin
    IsFirstRun := False;
    // Пердварительные действия
  end;

  Result := CallMyRecursion();
  // Вызов функции
End;
{$J-}
```

Также стоит почить [эту](http://www.sql.ru/forum/95545/tipizirovannaya-konstanta) ветку форума. Перед использованием хорошенько взвесьте, может вы обновитесь к следующей версии и все будет работать по другому. И недокументированная "фичу" исправят как баг.

Comment: @KromStern, дополнил ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Вспомнил. Основывалось на том, что при каждом новом входе в процедуру или функцию локально объявленные типизированные константы заново не инициализируются, а через типизированный указатель мы их можем изменять, как это не странно. Выглядеть будет примерно так:

```
Procedure CallMyRecursion(...);
Var
  PCounter: ^Integer;
Const
  Counter: Integer=0;
Begin
  PCounter:=@Counter;
  If Counter=0 Then Begin
    //Initialisation
  End;
  Inc(PCounter^);

  CallMyRecursion(...);
End;
```

Comment: Зачем городить такие сложности? Такой код намного сложнее для понимания. Чем вас не устраивает мой простой и логичный вариант? Менять константы через типизированный указатель - это круто. Но зачем? От того, что в каждой итерации нужно проверять условие и увеличивать счетчик, код быстрее работать не будет.

Comment: @kot-da-vinci, "Ваш простой логичный вариант" я описал в тексте самого вопроса, потому выдавать его за свой ну как-то не правильно чтоли. Во-вторых, если нам нужно писать в лог например на каждом 100ом или 1000ом шаге, то всё равно нужен счётчик. Мне интересны были варианты, иногда предлагают что-нибудь оригинальное или для меня новое... Всегда интересно рассмотреть все возможности и сделать выводы. Спасибо всем!